# Error no #1064, I followed all the guidelines but still?

Tags: mysql, sql

I followed every guideline but still, Is it because it has child tables?

```
DELIMITER //
create PROCEDURE insert_in_aadhar(aadhar_no bigint,addr text,DOB date,e_mail tinytext,Fnam varchar,genderr varchar,location int,Lnam
varchar,mobile bigint)
BEGIN
    INSERT into aadhar(aadhar,address,F_name,L_name,Gender,location_pin,date_of_birth,Phone_no,email)
values(aadhar_no,addr,DOB,e_mail,Fnam,genderr,location,Lnam,mobile);
End//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You do not even need a begin - end pair, nor delimiter change, since the body of the procedure is a single sql statement. Otherwise, pls share the exact error message because the near ... part contains important clue as to what could have gone wrong!

Answer (score 0):

VARCHAR needs a number of bytes behind it, else you get an error

```
DELIMITER //
create PROCEDURE insert_in_aadhar(aadhar_no bigint,addr text,DOB date,e_mail tinytext,Fnam varchar(100),genderr varchar(100),location int,Lnam varchar(100),mobile bigint)
BEGIN
    INSERT into aadhar(aadhar,address,F_name,L_name,Gender,location_pin,date_of_birth,Phone_no,email)
values(aadhar_no,addr,DOB,e_mail,Fnam,genderr,location,Lnam,mobile);
End//
DELIMITER ;
```

But as Shadow already told you, you don't need actuyll for thos a BEGIN and END, as long as you don't add more lines.

```
create PROCEDURE insert_in_aadhar(aadhar_no bigint,addr text,DOB date,e_mail tinytext,Fnam varchar(100),genderr varchar(100),location int,Lnam varchar(100),mobile bigint)
INSERT into aadhar(aadhar,address,F_name,L_name,Gender,location_pin,date_of_birth,Phone_no,email)
 values(aadhar_no,addr,DOB,e_mail,Fnam,genderr,location,Lnam,mobile);
```

Comment: Thank you so much... You helped me a lot